# Formula to search 3 words "text" in any sequence in different cell

Tags: excel, vba

Please take a look at the attached image. I have a long list of items and I've created a common keywords to search in that list. I'm using this formula:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH((("*"&B2&"*")&("*"&C2&"*")&("*"&D2&"*")&("*"&E2&"*")&("*"&F2&"*")),A:A,0))
```

The problem that the search is going through the same sequence that I entered.
It gives error if the sequence of the words in the cell is different than the sequence in my formula which make sense.

Is there a way I can search for 3 or more words that are existing in any cell in any sequence?

I am open to using VBA if necessary.

My search results:

[image: my search results]

Comment: What are you trying to do with the results?

Comment: I need to match 2 lists.. each list has the same items but each item is not exactly the very same as the other list.  i need to match each list with closest match from other list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the user defined function:

```
Public Function indexMX(rng As Range, pat1 As Range, pat2 As Range, pat3 As Range, pat4 As Range, pat5 As Range) As Variant
    Dim r As Range, rngx As Range, s(1 To 5) As String, Kount As Long, j As Long

    s(1) = pat1.Value
    s(2) = pat2.Value
    s(3) = pat3.Value
    s(4) = pat4.Value
    s(5) = pat5.Value

    Set rngx = Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange)

    For Each r In rngx
        v = r.Value
        Kount = 0
        For j = 1 To 5
            If InStr(1, v, s(j)) > 0 Or s(j) = "" Then Kount = Kount + 1
        Next j
        If Kount = 5 Then
            indexMX = v
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next r
    indexMX = "no luck"
End Function
```

Here is an example of its usage:

[image]

As you see, we give the UDF() the address of the column and the addresses of the five keywords and the UDF() finds the first item containing all five words.

If a keyword is blank, it is not used. *(so if you want to search for only two keywords, leave the other three blank)*.  If no matches are found the phrase ***no luck*** is returned.

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**EDIT#1:**

to remove case sensitivity, replace:

```
If InStr(1, v, s(j)) > 0 Or s(j) = "" Then Kount = Kount + 1
```

with:

```
If InStr(1, LCase(v), LCase(s(j))) > 0 Or s(j) = "" Then Kount = Kount + 1
```

Comment: thank you very very much.. i'm sure this will solve my problem eventually.. but its still giving me "no luck" i'm sure there is something i'm missing.. i will try to attach a photo here

Comment: i didn't find a way to add an picture.. here is the used formula:  =indexMX(A:A,B2,C2,E2,G2,I2)

Comment: @SamKay  pay careful attention to upper/lower case.......also watch out for accidental blanks, etc.

Comment: I need one more favor, I need to add your formula to the Index,match formula because i'm looking in a different sheet and matching from that sheet

Comment: @SamKay  For a column in a different sheet, use something like `=indexmx(Sheet6!A:A,C1,D1,E1,F1,G1)`

Comment: so i don't have to add the "Match" function?

Comment: is there is away to ignore uppercase?  because you were right, its case sensitive and that's why it returned error

Comment: @SamKay  If you look at my Picture, the `INDEX()?MATCH()` thing is all built-in

Comment: you are super genius :)  how about the case sensitive issue?

Comment: works like a charm... thank you thank you thank you :)))

Comment: @garys-student can i ask one more favor? i found that some result in the given VBA Code are returning by default first available item. example: I was searching for "Homeostatic Mosquito Scissors", and the result came with "Halsted-Mosquito Homeostatic Scissors" but this is not the one i want.  I don't want the Halsted one.

Comment: my question no. 1: is there is away i can exclude certain text from the search string (like adding one more column to include any unwanted text (if any)?

Comment: my question no. 2: is there is away i can get all results with that have the searching words and i choose among best result?  like i get a list of all results includes Homeostatic Mosquito Scissors which are around 10 results?

Comment: please I need a final help in yesterday's tow questions: can i exclude particular text from my search? and can i have multiple possible results?  at least adding one more column to exclude its contents will do the job.  thanks

Comment: @SamKay  If you need multiple results and special exclusions, then I would not use this **UDF()**.  I would use an *AutoFilter* with a helper column...this support multiple criteria and exclusions and multiple results.

Comment: @SamKay You could also consider using a **Sub()** rather than a **Udf()**.........it is easier to program a sub to achieve what you desire.

Comment: thank you very much sir.. i will take your advice and work on it.  appreciate your help sir..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible for a single cell to return three matching words from a different cell.  The answer in this example uses a formula to return 6 matches.   VBA and special array functions are not used.

This is the formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUMPRODUCT((IFERROR(SEARCH(FIRST,TARGET),0)>0)*100000+(IFERROR(SEARCH(SECOND,TARGET),0)>0)*20000+(IFERROR(SEARCH(THIRD,TARGET),0)>0)*3000+(IFERROR(SEARCH(FOURTH,TARGET),0)>0)*400+(IFERROR(SEARCH(FIFTH,TARGET),0)>0)*50+(IFERROR(SEARCH(SIXTH,TARGET),0)>0)*6),"1",FIRST&DELIM),"2",SECOND&DELIM),"3",THIRD&DELIM),"4",FOURTH&DELIM),"5",FIFTH&DELIM),"6",SIXTH&DELIM),"0","")
```

Did you notice the named ranges?  FIRST, SECOND, THIRD, etc are individual cells and each one holds a word. We are trying to find those words inside TARGET. If we find the words, then we will write them in this cell holding this formula and each word will be separated by DELIM

The ranges are optional.  In the picture below, you'll see cell A2 contains the word "named". This is the first of the six words we're tying to find and it can be expressed as FIRST = "A2" = "named"  Inside the formula you'll see that FIRST appears twice.  You could replace it with "named" and the cell A2 would become blank but the functionality of the formula would not change.

Even TARGET is optional.  It could be written as E1 or typed out word for word. 
 I don't know why anyone would do that... but it is possible.

DELIM is at cell B2, it is a double space

[image]

Now to explain how it works

SEARCH(search for what?,  search where?) This is responsible for determining if a match exists or not.  If you understand what the named ranges then you've already figured out the syntax is. The location of first letter that of match in  TARGET is returned.  In this formula it is always 1  If it is not found then the number is 0

IFERROR(value,value) tries to perform the operation.  If successful then the result is displayed. If there's an error the second result is displayed.  Every IFERROR in this formula is practically the same:  `IFERROR(SEARCH(FIRST,TARGET),0)` It searches inside TARGET trying to find the FIRST word.  Result if found is 1 and if not found is 0

It gets a little more complicated from here so lets recap.  We're calling SEARCH 6 times.  Once for each word we want to find and we're always looking in TARGET.  Result will be a 1 if match is found or a 0 if not. Ironically, us humans can put it together and see the match but the formula can't determine which words have been matched without more information

SUMPRODUCT takes the sum (addition) of the product (multiplication) of two or more arrays.

multiply two arrays to get the product
`a, b, c  *  e, f, g  =  ae, bf, cg
takethe sum of the product to get the SUMPRODUCT`
ae + bf + cg`

This is easiest when thought of a price  and quantity.  If one array is the price of a group of items and the other is quantity of the same group of items, then multiplying the two arrays will create a new array where each element is the cost to buy all items of that type in the group the total, and adding all those numbers give you the total cost you'd pay for all of the items

Here we multiply two arrays:

```
Qty    Price
12.0    0.3
70.0    0.1
20.0    0.4
```

Multiply them to get the product:

```
Qty    Price    Total
12.0    0.3     3.8
70.0    0.1     7.0
20.0    0.4     8.0
```

Take the sum of the product:

```
Qty    Price    Total       
12.0    0.3     3.8     
70.0    0.1     7.0     
20.0    0.4     8.0     
                18.8 SUMPRODUCT
```

Lets look at part of the formula:

SUMPRODUCT((IFERROR(SEARCH(FIRST,TARGET),0)>0)*100000+IFERROR(SEARCH(SECOND,TARGET),0)>0)*20000+...

It is easy to see this segment is looking for two words.  We know SUMPRODUCT want's to multiply and add arrays.  If you're thinking `(IFERROR(SEARCH(FIRST,TARGET),0)>0)` is an array, you'd be right!  It's not an array in the technical sense of the word, but it does evaluate into a single value which can thought of as a 1x1 array, or, a cell.  The sharp eyed and quick witted, may have noticed there is something on this array we have mentioned.  It's the inequality at the end! Many of you know that you can take numerical values and turn them into boolean by testing them with an inequality.  So lets evaluate.... SEARCH for FIRST inside TARGET = 1 because FIRST = "named" which is inside TARGET waaaaaaay in the back and because it wasn't an error we get to keep the 1.  Next we do the inequality  1 > 0 = TRUE  One is greater than zero and evaluates to TRUE

This is what we have right now

```
SUMPRODUCT((TRUE*100000+IFERROR(SEARCH(SECOND,TARGET),0)>0)*20000+....
```

Can you identify the arrays now?  We know TRUE is an array, a 1x1.  You know the IFERROR bit all the way to the inequality is also an array.  Lets evaluate that IFERROR .... Mathematically we should still be working from left to right but trust me, we're ok if we let it slide this once.

```
IFERROR(SEARCH(SECOND,TARGET),0)>0)    SECOND = "array" = 1 = TRUE
```

Did you follow my short hand?  It's ok if you didn't just back up and practice on FIRST until you understand.

Plugging in the value gives us something like this

```
SUMPRODUCT(TRUE*100000+TRUE*20000+...
```

SUMPRODUCT is the SUM(addition) of the PRODUCT(multiplication)
So we're adding the stuff we multiply

```
SUMPRODUCT = (TRUE * 100000) +  (TRUE * 20000)
```

Remember how easy it was to go from 1 > 0 to TRUE. We're "getting all up into that boolean TRUE that" equals 1   Here's a fun fact, -1 is also equal to TRUE. If you've ever seen a formula with a double negative in it like this STUFF(--(MORESTUFF( that's just some Excel wizard person making sure they get a +1 instead of a -1  ... ok, so lets get back on track and evalute

```
SUMPRODCUT = 1 * 100000 + 1 * 20000+....
SUMPRODCUT =  100000 + 20000+....
SUMPRODCUT =  120000+.....
```

I know you've been asking about those numbers. One hundred thousand?  What's one hundred thousand for?  I've been purposefully ignoring until it became convenient to talk about it.  And now it's convenient.  Go look at the whoooole formula and you'll find a pattern.  Those numbers are in a decreasing sequence.  Anyone who's ever done bitwise logic can see where this is going.I'm running short on time so I'll cut to the chase.  Assume a hypothetical situation where every word was matched. You'd end up with

```
SUMPRODUCT = 100000 + 20000 + 3000 + 400 + 50 + 6
SUMPRODCUT = 123456
```

123456 are you pulling my leg?  No, I am not. We're almost done so if you're still with me then you're gonna drive it home.

We have a large group of SUBSTITUTE teachers at the front of the line and we gotta get rid of them.

We also have this to contend with `:"1",FIRST&DELIM),"2",SECOND&DELIM),"3",THIRD&DELIM),"4",FOURTH&DELIM),"5",FIFTH&DELIM),"6",SIXTH&DELIM),"0","")`

Thankfully for us, they are part of the same problem.  We worked our way from the middle out.

```
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(text, old text, new text)
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("123456","1", FIRST & DELIM),"2",SECOND & DELIM)....
```

Remember at top DELIM was pointing to a cell holding a double space.  Each DELIM can be replaced with "  " or any other delimiter you want.

```
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("123456","1", "named" & "  "),"2",SECOND & DELIM)...
SUBSTITUTE("named  23456","2",SECOND & DELIM)...
SUBSTITUTE("named  23456","2","array"& "  ")...
("named  array  3456")... and so on.
```

Any questions?

Ok, class is dismissed!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.. I will give it a try tomorrow morning and let you know the result.. thanks again my dear :)

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work! i replaced all targets with my cells and applied but it returned with error and didn't accept.. keep saying: you've entered too few arguments for this function.  and more more thing, i did not know where to add my source file where the formula should search these keywords to find the best match!

Comment: Hi Sam, I'm not 100% the formula does what you need but it won't take long to find out.  I'm going to edit the answer to clarify the usage.

Comment: Hi @ProfoundlyOblivious thank you very much for the comprehensive explanation and for the time you spent on this.  I truly do appreciate your help sir.  I will follow the steps and see how it works.  Millions of thanks

Comment: It was genuinely my pleasure. I hope you find it useful.  Let me know if you want some help on the project you're working on.  I answered one of your other similar questions but later realized it really didn't solve your problem.

Comment: I really really appreciate your help.  i honestly tried on the formula you gave and i know that it should solve the problem if i used it the right way.  but for the lack of intelligence I couldn't apply it on my table..

Comment: but I need to clarify one thing that might be not clear in my original question: I have a list of products.. sometimes I receive from customers a request for one of these products.. the problem that every customer use his own description for the very same product. 
 so when i receive any request, i have to go through my long list which is more than 20,000 different items and i need to match the best item for that description.  -to be continued-

Comment: so as a part of the solution and after a long thinking, i've created a formula that will extend the 1st word and 2nd word and 3rd word from each item (form the list i receive from my customers) and another column to determine the category and another one for the shape.  and i was looking for a formula to search for these 5 keywords from my list and get the closest match.  that's in general my concern :)  I have received a VBA code (very thankfully) from previous answer that already solved my problem, but it generated a new concern -to be continued-

Comment: Don't fret the problem is mine for not truly understanding your problem.  Two things.  One,  I think I have a better understanding of what you need. and two, i will try to cook something up.

Comment: the code was successfully giving the matching product, but the new concern arise when i faced some products which as similar names with slightly differences.  so the code was always giving the first possible match.  i was trying to get either a list of possible matches or add a column to exclude certain words from the search.  hope i didn't talk too much but i wanted to really thank all of you guys for trying to help out.  cheers!

Comment: Sam, I think I have a solution.  But I need to know what version of excel you have.  You have power pivot and power query?

Comment: Hi.. I have office 365 ProPlus.. and yes i have power pivot but im not sure about the power query